# Ruby regex "contains a word"

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby, how can I write a regex to inspect a submission for a single word?

Imagine I have a web form that that accepts text.  I know if I want to see if the sentence --only-- contains "join" I can use

```
    if the_body == "join"
```

But that only works if the entire text submission is "join".

How do I catch a submission like this:

"I want to join your club?" or 
"Join me please"

Thanks!

Comment: Do you also want to catch `"Joint venture"`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it with

```
string =~ /join/i
# /i makes it case insensitive
```

or

```
string.match(/join/i)
```

A little update regarding the performance comment:

```
>> s = "i want to join your club"
>> n = 500000
=> 500000
>> Benchmark.bm do |x|
..     x.report { n.times { s.include? "join" } }
..   x.report { n.times { s =~ /join/ } }
..   end
       user     system      total        real
   0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.186184)
   0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.135985)
```

While the speed difference really doesn't matter here, the regex version was actually faster.

Comment: Except that there is no need to do a regex - which has a higher overhead than a plain string search.

Comment: Are you sure about the overhead? `String#include?` in the end uses a Rabin-Karp algorithm, which has a worst-case performance of O(mn), whereas a proper regex engine can probably do this in O(n).

Comment: Well, it's what I've always been told. Though I've not investigated to verify it - sounded plausible. So, no. I'm not sure. ;)

Comment: If it's hearsay and you haven't verified it yourself, you probably shouldn't mention it in your post and add it as comment to other posts ;-) I'd do agree though that `include?` actually conveys the semantics very well and the performance difference should be negligible in any case :-)

Comment: Sure, it will go back and forth in  various runs. All I tried to say is that semantics are probably a way better way to argue this question than performance. Anyway, OP asked for regex, I provided a regex answer. Personally I like them and use them a lot, but a lot of people seem to be averse to them.

Comment: When you add the OP's requirement to do a case-insensitive search, the regex was nearly twice as fast in my test.

Comment: FWIW, I just ran similar benchmarks to Michael's, and got the opposite result (with the regexp being consistently slower across many runs).  I agree with Michael that the semantics are more important, but I'm curious why I would see different performance than he got (I'm running an Ubuntu VM on a Windows system with ruby 1.9.2).

Comment: If string is `they are joining canals` and goal is to find exactly world `join` then this solution will fail or if string is `My friend Bonjoiny is a cool guy` again this solution may not work. It will incorrectly match a "word" - join

Comment: Update the regex then so that `join` is bounded by whitespace `\s`, beginning of string `\A` or end of string `\z`.

Answer (score 11):

Correct solution to find an exact WORD in a string is

`the_body.match(/\bjoin\b/i)` or use other regex:

`(\W|^)join(\W|$)`

Please note, we need to find whether "join" WORD exists or not in the string. All above solution will fail for strings like: `they are joining canals` or `My friend Bonjoiny is a cool guy`

Answer (score -1):

There's no need for Regexp here -- `String#include?` will do the job.

Comment: He/she wants an exact word.